# Add Axis Labels to ggcorrplot?

Tags: r, ggcorrplot

How do I add axis labels to a ggcorrplot?  I have a plot of the correlation between two separate attempts at a questionnaire.  X axis represents the first attempt, Y axis represents the second attempt.  I want to label the axes to show that this is what is being represented here.

My code looks like this:

```
corrQData <- round(cor(Attempt1, Attempt2), digits = 1)

ggcorrplot(corrQData, 
           outline.color = "white",
           ggtheme = theme_bw(),
           colors = c("#F8696B", "#FFEB84", "#63BE7B"),
           legend.title = "Correlation",
           lab = TRUE,
           lab_size = 3,
           tl.cex = 8,
           tl.srt = 0,
           title = "Correlation Between Questionnaire Attempts") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=10), legend.title = element_text(size = 10))
```

My plot looks like this:

[image]

I tried adding `+ scale_x_discreet(name = "Attempt 1")` to the end of my ggcorrplot code but it didn't do anything.

Comment: To find what was going wrong, you can inspect `ggcorrplot` code by typing in R's console `ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot` (without the parenthesis otherwise it calls the function). The answer is in the very last line of the function, which you can then inspect with `ggcorrplot:::.no_panel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the default behaviour of `ggcorrplot` which is not to display axis labels. Do that by adding labels with `ggplot2::labs()` (`scale_x_discrete(name = ...)` works fine also) and changing the plot's theme

```
library(ggcorrplot)
corrdata <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)

ggcorrplot(corrdata) + 
  ggplot2::labs(x = 'X label', y = 'Y label') +
  ggplot2::theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(angle = 0, color = 'grey20'),
    axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, color = 'grey20')
  )
```

Comment: Please note that `ggcorrplot` developers probably had a good reason not to display axis labels, so you might as well go along with that.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using {ggcorrplot2}.

While the the ggcorrplot developers may have good reasons for not including axis labels (eg they should not be necessary for a pairwise matrix), there are certain cases where it may make sense to desire specifying the axis labels and axis ticks. Eg. when comparing correlations across two different sets of variables, and excluding any comparisons made within sets.

---

ggcorrplot2::ggcorrplot() suppresses axis labels by internally using the following

```
theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

If you want to over-rule this and provide axis labels, you must both specify the labels to be added and re-specify the axis.title behavior, e.g

```
corrdata <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)

ggcorrplot2::ggcorrplot(corrdata) + 
  ggplot2::labs(x = 'Variable Set 1', y = 'Variable Set 2') +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.title = element_text())
```

One can also manually specify the axis tick labels as well using

```
corrdata <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)

ggcorrplot2::ggcorrplot(corrdata) + 
  ggplot2::labs(x = 'Variable Set 1', y = 'Variable Set 2') +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.title = element_text())+
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:dim(corrdata)[1], labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"), 
      expand = c(0, 0))+
  ggplot2::scale_y_reverse(breaks = 1:dim(corrdata)[1], labels = c("l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v"), 
      expand = c(0, 0))
```

[Plot with modified axis labeling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5vzR.png)